# AVD Droid X skins don't fit on the screen

Tags: eclipse-plugin, android-emulator

I'm teaching myself Android (using a book) and I've downloaded Tea Vui Huang's Droid X skin for the using with the Android SDK in Eclipse. When I run the emulator, the top of the window showing the Droid X's screen runs off the top of my laptop screen.  Is there anyway to make the skin smaller?  This happens with the WVGA854 skin that comes with Android, too.  Is this just the fact that the real Droid X screen is 854 pixels high, and my laptop is 768 high, and there's no way to "shrink" the Droid X emulator display?

There is a Windows trick that lets you move windows who's control bar has moved off screen.  I thought I could use it to slide the Window up and down so I could sequentially see the top and bottom, e.g. to access the app-tray button at the bottom of the screen.  Windows won't let me do this...once I start this trick, it won't let me leave the top of the window off-screen.

Any advice appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run it with -scale command line option.